# Authorize an AVS Device Through a Companion App

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to authorize an AVS device through a Companion App, but I'm unable get refresh token, only access token.
According to Alexa developer documentation for authorization (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-voice-service/authorize-companion-app.html#) you should get both (step 6)

According to LWA documentation (https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/authorization-code-grant.html#access-token-request) if you don't provide client secret you only get access token without refresh token.

According to Alexa requirement I can't store client secret on the device.

Post to: https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token only returns access token without refresh token.
If I provide client_secret I get both

Please help sort this out
Michael